# Is it a bad practice use Thread.sleep(Milliseconds) for wait a bit before start another activity?

Tags: java, android, thread-sleep

I'm making a SplashScreen for an app ... When the app starts, it start LoadingActivity ... sleep for 3 seconds, finish(); and then starts the MainActivity. Splash serves to update the database. If the database is already updated, I want the splash still for 3 seconds anyway.

I am using the following code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Is it a bad pratice? and why? The app is running nicelly in AVD.

Comment: If you run sleep in main UI then you are freezing the UI and it will lead to activty not responding error (ANR). Use handler postdelayed function.

Comment: Doing blocking operations on the main thread is *always* a bad idea, period.  `postdelayed` is the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sleeping on the UI thread is **always** a bad idea.  In this case you are in an `onPostExecute`, which is on the UI thread.

Throw your sleep into the `doInBackground` method of your `AsyncTask` instead, and you won't get any ANR's there (Android not responding).

Users don't like waiting for splash screens, so it is better not to wait at all.  But sometimes the splash screen is required (ie due to contracts).

Comment: I did not mention, but the Splash is needed to update the database (If outdated)

Comment: Then tell them what you are doing, and only stay there as long as you need to in order to accomplish it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is bad practice, `onPostExecute()` is called on UI thread so basically you are blocking your UI thread for 3 whole seconds. I suspect you want to show a splash screen. You can instead do it like this.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
     }
},3000);
```

**or** if you want to stick with `AsyncTask` then override `doInBackground()` and sleep in it and launch your `Activity` in `onPostExecute()` normally.

Comment: I did not mention, but the Splash is needed to update the database (If outdated) ... so I need Async right?

Comment: Yes then you need `AsyncTask`, sync your database in `doInBackground()` and then in `onPostExecute()` launch your next `Activity`.

Answer (score -4):

If this is is at the very start of the Programm you could do a while Loop that runns until System.currentTimeMillis() is higher than 3000 than it was at the Start of the program.

Comment: That's an even worse idea than sleeping.

Comment: Could you give a constructive comment an Tell me why?

Comment: Sleeping for 3 seconds will just block UI, whereas doing what you said will take processor usage to 100% for whole 3 seconds. That's why its worse.

Comment: There are probably other applications on the device with services running in the background.  In addition to blocking the UI thread, you are preventing them from doing any work, to.  Hence "worse".