# Android: Change Image twice onClick in onItemClickListener

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I have the below mentioned code in my Activity class'   onCreate() method.
As it may be obvious to some, this does not work, since the image is rendered only once, long afte the execution of onItemClick.

```
      gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.adaptorItemImageView);

            if(someCOMPLEXlogic)
            { // Line 1
              imageView.setImageResource(XXXXXX);
               // Line 2
              Thread.sleep(2000);
               // how to show one image, wait for 2 secs, and then show another one?
                 // Line 3
              imageView.setImageResource(YYYYYY);
              }
        }
    });
```

As a result , I only see Image YYYYYY.
I tried using Threads and AsyncTask, replacing Line 2 and Line 3 with a call to a new Thread(), which performed the same operations, but with errors like

```
A different thread cannot access UI thread views, 
 (Something Like that, I do not remember,apologies)
```

Can somebody give me the workaround to achieve the same behaviour without invoking a new activity.
Also can someone explain why this problem arose in the first place(Android doesn't render images immediately, how does it work?)

Comment: you are sleeping for 20 seconds..

Comment: You should avoid using `Thread.sleep` - you'll freeze your UI. Use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or something instead. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036676/is-it-a-bad-practice-use-thread-sleepmilliseconds-for-wait-a-bit-before-start

Comment: Let us assume I want to show an Image for 2 secs(question edited), and then show another image, will you be able to write the code here instead? Nothing else on the grid must change.

Comment: just use imageView.postDelayed(new Runable() {...}, 2000); in the Runable implement run method to change the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the postDelayed method of the view, like below. You may change the imageView to final though.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    final ImageView imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.adaptorItemImageView);

    if(someCOMPLEXlogic)
    { 
        imageView.setImageResource(XXXXXX);
        imageView.postDelayed(new Runable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageView.setImageResource(YYY);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, its working now, can you also please explain why it was not working the way I tried?

Comment: Because you use sleep to pause the main thread and the UI will not be updated until the thread resumes. After sleep for 2 seconds, you immediately update the image to another one and the previous one is simply ignored (as new image is set). The approach here is to *schedule* a message for the main thread to update the image and it immediately returns and thus UI is updated immediately. 2 seconds later, the UI received that schedule message and again update the UI.